# Is it possible to pass VBscript array to highchart series data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, highcharts

Is it possible to pass  arrays from Vbscript to HIghchart series?

How can i pass the arrays data 1 and data 2 to highchart series?
Currently it generates array using VBscript and I want to pass that array to Highchart, but it seems it notgettgin passed to highchart

Here is the **vbScript**  code and highchart code

```
<script language="JavaScript" runat="server">

    var title = "Test";
    var data1 = [];
    var data2 = [];

    function addToDataSeries1(data){
        data1.push(data);
    }

    function addToDataSeries2(data){
        data2.push(data);
    }

    function testJSHello(){
        return "Hello from JS";
    }
```

//This generates the arrays and outputs them perfectly, problem is when you pass //it to highchart nothing seems to be passed.
//If I do the same thing with PHP or data generated random from JS and passed to high chart it works.
Can anyone help?

```
    function returnData2ElementsAsString(){

        var series = "";
        for(var x = 0; x < data2.length-1; x++){
            series = series + data2[x] + ", "
        }
        return series;
    }

</script>
```

**HighChart**

```
<script language="JavaScript">
             $(document).ready(function() {

             /*
                var data1=[null, null, null, null, null, 6, 11, 32, 110, 235, 369, 640,
                    1005, 1436, 2063, 3057, 4618, 6444, 9822, 15468, 20434, 24126,
                    27387, 29459, 31056, 31982, 32040, 31233, 29224, 27342, 26662,
                    26956, 27912, 28999, 28965, 27826, 25579, 25722, 24826, 24605,
                    24304, 23464, 23708, 24099, 24357, 24237, 24401, 24344, 23586,
                    22380, 21004, 17287, 14747, 13076, 12555, 12144, 11009, 10950,
                    10871, 10824, 10577, 10527, 10475, 10421, 10358, 10295, 10104];

                 var data2 =  [null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null,
                    5, 25, 50, 120, 150, 200, 426, 660, 869, 1060, 1605, 2471, 3322,
                    4238, 5221, 6129, 7089, 8339, 9399, 10538, 11643, 13092, 14478,
                    15915, 17385, 19055, 21205, 23044, 25393, 27935, 30062, 32049,
                    33952, 35804, 37431, 39197, 45000, 43000, 41000, 39000, 37000,
                    35000, 33000, 31000, 29000, 27000, 25000, 24000, 23000, 22000,
                    21000, 20000, 19000, 18000, 18000, 17000, 16000];

                */

                var title =" Graph using random data ";            


                var mynumber=10;
                var data1 = [];
                for(var i=1; i<=mynumber; i++) {
                   data1.push(i.toString()*Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
                }

                var data2 = [];
                for(var i=1; i<=mynumber; i++) {
                   data2.push(i.toString()*Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1));
                }

                // PRINT data1
                /**    
                    for( var x=0;x <data1.length-1; x++) {
                        document.write("<br> x " +x+ " data1[]" +data1[x] + "");
                    }        
                 **/

      $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            title: {
                text: title
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'Source: <a href="http://thebulletin.metapress.com/content/c4120650912x74k7/fulltext.pdf">' +
                    'thebulletin.metapress.com</a>'
            },
            xAxis: {
                allowDecimals: false,
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value; // clean, unformatted number for year
                    }
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Sample bank monitor graph test '
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return this.value / 1000 + 'k';
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name} produced <b>{point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>warheads in {point.x}'
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    pointStart: 1940,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false,
                        symbol: 'circle',
                        radius: 2,
                        states: {
                            hover: {
                                enabled: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'USA',
                data: data1
            }, {
                name: 'USSR/Russia',
                data: data2
            }]
        });
            });  

</script>
```

Comment: That's Javascript in your first code section, not VBScript.

Comment: @mrunion Can you tell  then why is highchart not seeing data1 and data2 generated under runat="server". If i uncomment the static data1 and data2 , high chart works.

Comment: I would guess that it's because HighCharts is a Javascript library that runs on the CLIENT, and you are trying to write code that runs on the SERVER and uses HighCharts. You have to have code on the CLIENT to use HighCharts.

Comment: @mrunion - You mentioned the first code is javascript as well.. if that the case shouldnt high chart see that data?   Vb is not my expertise, but i tried passign the server side data through php  and stored it to js array and then passed to highchart array and that worked. Is there a way to pass vb array to highchart?

Comment: Short answer, yes. Do the same thing. Store the data in a Javascript array that is accessible on the client. That is a very broad topic, though, and I think you need more of a tutorial than a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: @mrunion Its already printing the arrays data1 and data2 it if you look at the first javascript with runat= server .The problem I am having is  in the second part of the JS for the highchart script its not seeing the values for data1 or data 2

Comment: JScript arrays are objects. VBScript arrays are COM SAFEARRAY chunks of memory. COM expects SAFEARRAYs. JScript can use VBScript arrays with the VBARRAY object. You cannot convert a JScript array to a VBScript array. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/22/jscript-and-vbscript-arrays/

Comment: @Noodles -  I am not trying to convert jJScript array to VBscript, I am trying to do is  pass the VBscript array to JScript array so i can pass the array to highchart series.

Comment: So, as I said, the JScript VBARRAY object. You have to read what people say.